# Google Analytics Events Tracking Module not working out of the box

Tags: google-analytics

I was super excited to learn about the [google_analytics_et](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics_et) module. I downloaded it and then uploaded to my staging site and enabled the modules like that mentioned. I then clicked around and notice that nothing happens like the documentation states. So I went to the internet to search for some answers. Nothing that helps me.

I am hoping that someone has some information. I wanted to add event tracking and the module seems to have promise. Is there a trick to getting it to work. Do I need to add javascript to the site, example module to make it work?

Is there a better way? Not being a developer is making it harder to figure out.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Okay I understand that I asked something a little too juvenile and could have spent another 10 hours figuring this out. I will try to reword the question. However this is a drupal module question and valid since I am a little less aware of the module versions and dependancies. When it doesn't work I am not a developer so I cannot fix myself. I was trying to understand if someone found something I did not find while searching the forums and through google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No JS additions are needed; that's taken care of for you. The GA Events Tracking module doesn't work by itself however, it requires 2 things:

- The [GA module](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics).
- A module implementing `hook_google_analytics_et_api()`.

The module includes an [example module](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/google_analytics_et/tree/google_analytics_et_example?id=69135bf) which you can either alter directly (not recommended) or just create a renamed copy of it (renaming files & functions from `google_analytics_et_example` to `mymodule`). More information can be found on the [project page](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics_et) on what you need to do. It does require you to know a little something about:

- **jQuery:** To set the appropriate [event](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events) (e.g. `mousedown`) & [selector](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) (e.g. `#main-menu li a`).
- **[Google Analytics Event Tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events):** (to set the right data for the event).

Comment: I do have the GA Module and _et module installed. I have also copied and renamed the example module. I tested it like the page mentioned, however, that never created a message. like ti mentioned. I also added the correct jQuery based on using the Universal Analytics. So - ga(‘send’, ‘event’, ‘Newsletter Print/PDF’, ‘printclick’, ‘Newsletter Page’, 4); - in the example module. - I also have the Event Tracking in the 'Advanced Settings / Custom JS Code'
$('#newsletterPrint').on('click', function() {
  ga('send', 'event', 'Newsletter Print/PDF', 'printclick', 'Newsletter Page', 1);
});

Comment: Not sure what I might be missing.

Comment: Okay finally figure out that the module was not up-to-date.